# HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway- The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process after upgrading to RC1

Tags: dnx

I am getting this error only on PUT after upgrading dnx to 1.0.0 rc1 update. In eventvwr, I can see the below logged as Application Error:

> Faulting application name: dnx.exe, version: 1.0.0.11123, time stamp:
>   0x5653996f Faulting module name: MSVCR80.dll, version: 8.0.50727.9193,
>   time stamp: 0x56048aec Exception code: 0xc000000d Fault offset:
>   0x000000000001da44 Faulting process id: 0x1958 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d173a169bd9f64 Faulting application path:
>   ..\approot\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnx.exe
>   Faulting module path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.9193_none_88e4514b2faac6c7\MSVCR80.dll
>   Report Id: 97c4f341-6aee-4165-a317-ebd49827598b Faulting package full
>   name: Faulting package-relative application ID:

I can see HttpPlatformHandler installed and rc1 update as well. The appPool is running with my credentials. DNX is also running.
I have seen the stdoutLogFile where the below is logged.

> "Hosting environment: Production Now listening on:
>   http://localhost:5000 Now listening on: http://localhost:26959
>   Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down."

Had anyone faced this issue earlier?

Comment: The error message is misleading, you will need to debug/log it to find out what the exact exception is. Mine was because I'm using wrong connection string.